# Rails money-rails: Is it necessary the monetize model definition if using migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, money-rails

Im a little bit confused with the documentation of [money-rails](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails), they say that if you have an integer column called "price_cents" you just need to add the `monetize :price_cents` definition in the model, however they also say that you can add the money field in database migration like:

```
def change
    add_money :products, :price
end
```

But my doubt is: if I use the migration helper `add_money` then I need to also add the `monetize` definition in the model? or is it only necessary when you have an integer column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, both are necessary.  `monetize :price_cents` creates the facade that allows you to use `Product.price = 10.99`, and set the price_cents column behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks, late but at useful